# JavaFx PieChart boundary colors

Tags: css, javafx, pie-chart

When i build a pie chart in javafx, the boundary lines are always white.( I can set default slice colors with css). how can i set custom colors to boundary lines?

Comment: Can you attach an image. I don't see any white lines in a pie chart. Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying some css to the [standard chart sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD):

```
.chart-pie {
    -fx-border-color: derive(-fx-pie-color, -40%);
    -fx-border-width: 3px;
}
```

You can play around with other css settings to get the different effects you want.

I won't answer further questions on this, but instead read the Region specification in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) (as chart pies are styled regions) and review the [modena.css stylesheet](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors/openjfx-8-master-rt/src/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css?at=default) to learn how this can be done.

Here is the output with the css above applied:

[image: fruity]

Compared to the standard output with no additional CSS (using the default JavaFX 8 modena style):

[image: boringfruit]

Comment: now i see, the op meant the white border of the regions, while I was stuck looking at the circumference :)

Comment: i am sorry @ItachiUchiha. i was not allowed to attach image because of my rep.

Comment: @Itachi Yes, I was confused initially, too.  My initial approach was using multiple layered backgrounds to provide outlines within the segmented pie pieces, retaining the white separators, but on re-reading the question (which was clear on second reading), that wasn't what cek was looking for.