# How to remove PieChart white border between slices?

Tags: java, css, javafx, charts, styles

Is it possible to remove this white border between `PieChart` slices in JavaFX?
[image: White border]

I can't achieve it with the following style:

```
.chart-pie {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: I think it's already been answered
Try with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736918/javafx-piechart-boundary-colors?rq=1

Comment: @Nikolas This is not relevent, it's just a normal PieChart without anything special.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx PieChart boundary colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736918/javafx-piechart-boundary-colors)

Comment: I think this is a slightly different question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736918/javafx-piechart-boundary-colors because to remove the white lines (i.e. the border) you would have to keep track of pie slice x-1's color and fill in each border instance with the previous slice's color, no?

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the expected result is not a colored border of separated parts but the gap width between them itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the `PieChart` has an inset, i achieve it with :

```
.chart-pie {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

[image: Pie Chart]

It's not perfect but enought for me.

Answer (score 3):

By default, there is a gap between the parts and unfortunately, I haven't found how to change its width. However, you can create a border to fill the empty space (`-fx-border-width: 1px`) around the part using its color (`-fx-border-color: derive(-fx-pie-color, 0%)`). Create this stylesheet file.

```
.chart-pie {
    -fx-border-color: derive(-fx-pie-color, 0%);
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

Include it in the Scene.

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```

The result is displayed in the following picture. Feel free to adjust values to get the best result.

[image]

Edit: I have found that the [-fx-background-insets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) controls the size between values separated by commas, as the documentation sais:

> A series of size values or sets of four size values, separated by commas. A single size value means all insets are the same. Otherwise, the four values for each inset are given in the order top, right, bottom, left. Each comma-separated value or set of values in the series applies to the corresponding background color.

Thus the following style should give you the very same result:

```
.chart-pie {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

Edit2: Seems @TheZopo was a bit faster.